# Assembly program is printing newline

Tags: macos, assembly

So I wrote this simple assembly program. I made hello and world separate for practice.

```
    .cstring
hello:
    .ascii "hello "
    .text
world:
    .ascii "world\0"
    .text
.globl _main
_main:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    subl $8, %esp
    movl $hello, (%esp)
    call _puts
    movl $world, (%esp)
    call _puts
    xorl %eax, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .subsections_via_symbols
```

I am running Mac OS X with an Intel processor. This program is printing a newline character every time I call puts. Can someone explain to me why it's doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Because that's [what `puts(3)` *does*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/puts.3.html).

> The function **puts()** writes the string *s*, and a terminating newline character, to the stream stdout.